# If I mix C++ code in Objective C who manages memory for C++ object would ARC handle it?

Tags: c++, objective-c

If I create/allocate C++ objects in objective C such that Objective C objects are using pointers of the C++ objects and the code is intermingled will ARC manage C++ objects too and release/free them ?? 
What happens to C++ object whose pointer is in a Objetive C object which is not accessible ? and proposed candidate for removal from memory ??

Comment: I like the idea of this question (and upvoted it) but it would be nice if you could clarify exactly what your questions are.

Comment: I'm guessing that who allocated will have to delete, Objective C mechanics will not auto deallocate for you. Especially since pointer does not mean dynamic memory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Cocoa Core Competencies: Object life cycle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/ObjectLifeCycle.html), you should free resources in the `dealloc` method. For a "raw" C++ pointer, this means writing a `delete` expression.

ARC's part is to insert `retain` and `release` calls such that `dealloc` happens once an object is no longer accessible.

Answer (score 0):

For C++ objects the C++ mechanism is used and if you use ARC they will not be automatically counted. And Objective-C objects are managed with ARC (or manual counting if you don't use ARC).